# Swift CollectiionView タップ数を表示

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

SwiftでCollectionViewCellをタップした際にセル一つ一つのタップ数をカウントし、そのセルの中にセルごとに表示させる方法が知りたいです。カウントは、アプリの起動から終了までです。 このコードの中にどのように書けば良いでしょうか？
まだ初心者で質問がわかりにくい部分もあると思いますがよろしくお願いします。

` //セル選択時に呼び出されるメソッド

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let testCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SekiCollectionViewCell
```

`

Comment: 回答ではないので、コメント欄で質問させてもらいますが、`indexPath.row % 1`という式は、`0`以外にはならない（必ず`0`になる）のですが、それでいいのでしょうか？なにか書き間違いがあるのでしたら、**編集**をクリックすることで、質問文の再編集ができますから、訂正願います。

Comment: 編集しました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。それでは、ほんとうに質問したいことを質問します。「タップ数をカウント」の具体的な仕様を説明してください。セルひとつひとつのタップ数を、それぞれカウントするのか、Collection View全体のタップ数をカウントするのか？どこに表示するのか？いつからいつまでカウントするのか？開始ボタンを押して、終了ボタンを押すまで？画面遷移するまで？アプリをインストールしてから継続してカウントするのか？

Comment: セル一つ一つのタップ数をカウントする仕様にしたいと考えています。アプリの起動から終了までです。

Comment: コメント欄にでなく、質問文の編集という形で、私の質問にお答えください。そして、「どこに」を答えていただいていませんので、それもご記入ください。

Answer (score 1):

簡単な例を挙げてお答えします。(Swift3として記述)

質問者さんが挙げたメソッドの他に、以下のようなプロパティを持たせてみてください。
Dictionary型である必要はなく、あくまで簡単な例として置いています。

```
// 各セル毎のタップ数を格納する変数
private var tapCount = [IndexPath: UInt]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
    let before = self.tapCount[indexPath] ?? 0
    let after = before + 1

    self.tapCount[indexPath] = after

    print("cell at [section: \(indexPath.section), index: \(indexPath.row)] was tapped \(after) times in total.")
}
```

今回はタップ数をログで出力していますが、質問者さんの都合のいいように
利用して表示して見てください。

この例はセルの数や配置が変更された場合に対応できません。
望ましいのはセル自体にタップ数を持たせてやる方法ですね。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます！新しくメソッドに追加してみましたが、IndexPathにエラーが出てしまいました…どのように改善すれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: indexPathにエラーが出たということで

Comment: indexPathにエラーが出たということですが、
どのようなエラーでしょうか？もしかするとSwiftのverが問題になっているかとも思います。
教えていただけませんか？

Comment: エラーメッセージはUse of unresolved identifier "IndexPath"と表示されました。

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
    let before = self.tapCount[indexPath] ?? 0
    let after = before + 1

    self.tapCount[indexPath] = after

    print("cell at [section: \(indexPath.section), index: \(indexPath.row)] was tapped \(after) times in total.")
}

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
というメソッドはUITableViewDataSourceというプロトコルに用意されているメソッドです。このメソッドを用いれば必ずindexPathはこのメソッド内で使用できる自動変数となります。

Comment: おそらくSwiftのver（Xcodeのverの違いといった方がわかりやすいかも）が違うのだと思います。メソッド名が3.0から変更されていれば、

Comment: IndexPathのエラーは解決することができました！ jobtrainingonbsさんが言われていた通り、verの違いでNSIndexPathにすれば解決できました！実行はできるようになったのですが、画面が真っ白になります…